# Ruby date-time string to epoch time local

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have date-time represented in string format like below in the input data I'm getting. I need to convert this to epoch time local. How do I go about this ?

example date-time string

```
str = "Aug 23  2018 03:49:17:017 PM IST"
```

Comment: Please edit to define "epoch time local" (especially "epoch")?

Comment: “How do I go about this?”—you implement parsing of this string with [`Time#strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) and then you implement the printing as epoch time with `#strftime`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can put you on track.
Please refer to http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0//libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html.

This is a usage example.

```
require 'date'

str = "Aug 23  2018 03:49:17:017 PM IST"
d = DateTime.strptime(str, '%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S:%L %p %z')

# Maybe you need %e - Day of the month, blank-padded ( 1..31) instead of %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)

p d.hour # => 15
p d.min # => 49
p d.sec # => 17
p d.second_fraction # => (17/1000)
p d.day # => 23
p d.month # => 8
p d.year # => 2018
p d.zone # => "+05:30"

# this way you can switch timezone
d = d.new_offset('utc')
p d.zone # => "+00:00"
p d.hour # => 10
d = d.new_offset('brt')
p d.hour # => 7
p d.zone # => "-03:00"

# to print back as string, use strftime:
p d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %z') # => "2018-08-23 07:19:17 -0300"
```